# Issue On Targeting Closest Class to Toggle two Classes

Tags: jquery

Why I am not able to toggle classes `'fa-minus-circle fa-plus-circle'` ?

I am using the following code:

```
$('.faq-q').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.arrows').find('.fa-change').toggleClass('fa-minus-circle fa-plus-circle');
    $(this).closest('.fa-change').toggleClass('fa-minus-circle fa-plus-circle');
})
```

but is is not doing the job.

fiddle: http://www.bootply.com/hHWNJaNGv0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.closest()` method selects the first element that matches the selector up from the DOM tree.
You'll have to use `.find()` here

```
 $('.faq-q').on('click', function () {
    $(this).find('.fa-change').toggleClass('fa-minus-circle fa-plus-circle');
    $(this).find('.fa-change').toggleClass('fa-minus-circle fa-plus-circle');
})
```